# C Programming Book Error or Programming Error?

Tags: c, printf, stdout

```
int main()
{
// Initialize & Declare variable
int m = 5;

// Allocates memory for storage of an integer variable
int *itemp;

// Stores memory address of variable m in memory address itemp
itemp = &m;
// Notice after declaring pointer you don't need to reference it as a pointer

// asterick is also known as indirection operator
// indirect reference: Accessing the contents of a memory cell through a pointer variable that stores it's address

// We can rewrite the contents in the memory cell as such
*itemp = 35;
printf("%d",*itemp);

// Doubles the value of m
*itemp = 2 * *itemp;
printf("%d",*itemp);

return 0;
}
```

It's returning `3570` instead of `70`, which is what the book says it should be returning. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are printing`*itemp` 2 times. first time its value is `35` , second times its `70` . So its printing `3570`.

Comment: Your comment for the pointer is wrong. It "allocates" memory for the storage of a *pointer to an `int`*.

Comment: You're not programming if you don't say "Wow, stupid me..." at least a few times a day.

Comment: Just change first printf("%d",*itemp); to printf("%d\n",*itemp); and see the magic. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is correct. It is printing what it is coded to print.

To clarify,

1. You have two `printf()`s, printing `35` and `70`.
2. You don't have a "seperator" [for example, a *newline* (`\n`)] in your `printf()`s to distinguish the outputs of two print statements.

Result: You're seeing the final output `3570` as the combination of the output from two print statements, `35` and `70`.

Solution: Add a `\n` or `\t` at the end of the format string supplied in `printf()` to  add a visual *seperator* after each `printf()` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Buffering is irrelevant here. As there is no pause between printf's, the human is unable to see '35' printed before '70' anyway.

Comment: I think he/she means that it's nothing to do with buffering because nothing happens between the two printtfs, without buffering it'd be identical.

Comment: @teppic Aah, I see. Was thinking too much maybe. I'll simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
printf("%d\n",*itemp);
```

You are seeing 35 and 70 as output in the same line either add a space between them or a newline.